# Is there anyway to play MP4 file in assets folder with VideoView?

Tags: android, video, android-videoview, android-assets

I've searched for this question and all the answers are talking about using `raw` resource folder.

I need to use the `assets` folder because the app loads the video file very slowly. So, I want to reduce the time and show the video directly.

```
<VideoView
        android:id="@+id/vv_video"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

Using `setVideoPath()`

```
val uri = "file:///android_asset/intro.mp4"
vv_video.setVideoPath(uri)
vv_video.start()
```

```
val uri = "android.resource://$packageName/intro.mp4"; // I did try without the extension. But didn't work.
vv_video.setVideoPath(uri)
vv_video.start()
```

Using `setVideoURL()`

```
val uri = "file:///android_asset/intro.mp4"
vv_video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uri))
vv_video.start()
```

```
val uri = "android.resource://$packageName/intro.mp4"; // I did try without the extension. But didn't work.
vv_video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uri))
vv_video.start()
```

All didn't work. I tried with the `raw` folder. And it worked well.

How can I solve this problem? Or is there any way to load video quicker than using `raw`??

Comment: All the answers on SO suggest playing from the RAW folder. Why don't you go with the same?

Comment: @RahulKhurana because it loads slower as I stated in the question.

Comment: Can you explain how much time it takes? I've used the same many times and it works very well